# Getting "Insufficient memory " exception on exporting large data table to excel

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, datatable, export-to-excel

I have a data table which contains more than 125 000 records. I am trying to export this data table into an excel file. If the record count is less, then my code works perfectly. But in this case, the system is throwing the below exception:

> Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

Below is the code segment where the exception is thrown.
rawData is a 2 dimensional array made out of my data table.

```
Dim excelRange As String = String.Format("A1:{0}{1}", finalColLetter, dt.Rows.Count + 1)
excelSheet.Range(excelRange, Type.Missing).Value2 = rawData
```

Is there any way to handle such large data?

Comment: There are only 1.04 million lines in a worksheet.  If you are over that it will not work.

Comment: For a data set that large, you should be working in a database environment like SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

trying to stuff large amounts of data into a memory like that isn't going to work very well, as you can probably tell.

if you want to move large amounts of data like that you either want to handle it one row at time, adding your data to the file as you go, or export your data in batches.
that way you can free up memory as you go, disposing of data that's already been uploaded. Instead of stuffing the entire thing into memory all at once.